# Accessing logs of a running docker container

Tags: docker

How can I access the stdout & stderr of a running docker container?

When I inspect the container with `docker inspect <id> | grep log` I receive the following:

```
"LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/<long id>-json.log"
```

But I can't find the file neither on my current folder, nor when trying to run `docker exec <id> cat /var/lib/docker/containers/<long id>-json.log`

**edit** running `docker log <id>` doesn’t give anything either

---

I am launching the container with the following command:

`docker run -d -it --log-driver json-file --rm --log-opt max-size=10m --log-opt max-file=3 <my_app>`

What am I missing/forgetting?

Comment: This is the file on your computer, not inside the container, inside the container's directory.

Comment: All of the evidence you’re showing here suggests that the container simply isn’t writing anything to its stdout/stderr.  What is the container running?

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
docker logs <container ID>
```

Comment: I tried that already (sorry I will add it to my question) but it gives nothing